# Inspect font/text of a pop-up bubble displayed when a required field is missing value - using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, popup, webdriver

Using Selenium-Java 2.47.1, I see this pop-up bubble/balloon that gets displayed whenever the 'submit' button is clicked and a required field is missing a value.  I'm unable to inspect the bubble with firebug or DevTools. I need to be able to get the text and font.

[Here is a link to an image of the bubble](http://imgur.com/ArtlbUz), it's very simple, I just can't seem to figure this out. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Firebug you can select Break On Mutate in the HTML tab (The pause button with brackets).  Click the submit button, and Firebug will tell you what element is being added.